# Writing Ajax Form with IF ELSE statements...where did I go wrong?

Tags: jquery, ajax, if-statement

Need some help with a #jQuery issue. Can someone look at [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/writing-ajax-form-with-if-else-statements) and tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: What about your HTML? Specifically, what does your "form" tag look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#MyForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    ...
```

i'd try that.

Comment: According to the jQuery documentation, returning false from an event handler should be the same as calling preventDefault() and stopPropagation().

Comment: i'd like it if "should be" meant "is"

Answer (score 0):

Use the validate approach like:

```
var v = jQuery("#newsletterForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
         var str =  $("#newsletterForm").serialize(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/_addNewsletterUser.php",
            data: str,
            success: function() {

                $('#newsletter_form').hide();
                $('#thankyounewsletter').show();

            }

        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: May want to note that this requires the validation plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: This is nice but there remains the question of why the handler in the original question, which certainly looks like it should return false, is not preventing the form submission from continuing.

Comment: @Pointy: It only validates, I tried it but wanted my error messages to have a custom look. Not sure I want to use that...was planning on it initially but I don't want to use it for this project.